# Angular service object when setting config in app.module.ts

Tags: angular, typescript

In my angular code, I added code in main.ts, which call my service to load the config

main.ts

```
  myConfigService.loadConfig();
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).catch(err => 
    console.log(err));
```

in  myService code

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Utilities } from './misc/utilities';
import { LogLevel } from 'msal';


export let config: any = {};

@Injectable()
export class MyConfigService {
  public loadAppConfig() {
    config = {clientId: 'asdkjflkjfadslfkj', popUp: true};
  }
}
```

In my app.module.ts

```
import { config } from './services/my-config.service';

importS: [
  MsalModule.forRoot({
    clientId: config.clientId
  })
]
```

When I debug thru the code, the service is setting the export config object. When I get to the app.module.ts, the clientId is undefined.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `loadAppConfig()` instead of `myConfigService.loadConfig();` in main.ts ?

Answer (score 2):

`main.ts` is not a module but a simple script-file, executed from top to bottom. It is referenced only by `angular-cli.json` for handling the startup of the application.

**Solution: 1:**

The `Injectable` `MyConfigService` is only available when the `AppModule` gets loaded and it's scope/providers etc are defined/available for use by the application. So whatever you see while bootstrapping is not available for your app to use.

You should be using the `providers` array of `AppModule` to set up and load any initial configuration.

```
 providers: [{
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initializeMyApp,
            deps: [MyConfigService ],
            multi: true
        },
    ],


export function initializeMyApp(myConfigService : MyConfigService ) {
  return (): Promise<any> => myConfigService.loadConfig()   
              //Make sure to return a promise!
                             .toPromise().then( config: any) => {
                        // some logic here 
               }
}
```

**Solution 2:**

1. Add a `JSON` config file to the `/src/assets/` folder (so that is copied on build)
2. Create an MyConfigService to load and distribute the config
3. Load the configuration using an `APP_INITIALISER` as shown above in Solution 1.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the guidance. I added the providers section but I got the following error  StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken Application Initializer -> MyConfigService

Comment: I think this error occurs because you need to import your service or any other dependency used ( like `HttpClientModule`) in service to the AppModule